# Solve this equation explicitly for $\beta$

Tags: equation-solving, complex

Solve this equation explicitly for $\beta$:
$$T_{12}=\frac{x_{11}+x_{22}}{1+|\beta|^2}\beta$$
$x_{11}$ and $x_{22}$ are positive real numbers where $x_{11}>x_{22}$ and $T_{12}$ and $\beta$ are complex numbers. and $|\beta|<1$

Up to know I've tried this:

```
sol1 = Solve[
 Subscript[T, 12] == (Subscript[x, 11] + Subscript[x, 22])/(1 + Abs[β]^2) β &&
  {Subscript[x, 11], Subscript[x, 22]} ∈ Reals &&
  {Subscript[T, 12], β} ∈ Complexes,
 β
]
```

But it gives a complicated solution whereas the answer should be
$$\beta=\frac{T_{12}}{|T_{12}|}\sqrt{\frac{x_{22}}{x_{11}}}$$
according to the [scientific article](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx_9vCAvXd5kSjhIRVdybHZPQlk/view?usp=sharing) that I'm studying.

Comment: `sol1 = Block[{$Assumptions = Subscript[x, 11] > Subscript[x, 22] > 0 && {Subscript[x, 11], Subscript[x, 22]} \[Element] Reals && Subscript[T, 12] \[Element] Complexes}, Solve[Subscript[T, 12] == ((Subscript[x, 11] + Subscript[x, 22]) \[Beta])/(1 + Abs[\[Beta]]^2), \[Beta], Complexes]]` seems to work, but adding `Abs[\[Beta]] < 1` in `Solve` takes too long.

Comment: your answer cant be correct. the x's are a sum in the original, how can they appear otherwise in the result?

Answer (score 2):

**Edited to provide greater detail**

```
eq = Subscript[T, 12] == (Subscript[x, 11] + Subscript[x, 22])/(1 + Abs[β]^2) β
```

First determine `Abs[β]`

```
Simplify[ComplexExpand[Abs[#] & /@ eq, {Subscript[T, 12], β}, 
    TargetFunctions -> Abs], Subscript[x, 11] + Subscript[x, 22] > 0]
(* (1 + Abs[β]^2) Abs[Subscript[T, 12]] == Abs[β] (Subscript[x, 11] + Subscript[x, 22]) *)

Simplify[Solve[%, Abs[β]]] // Flatten
(* {Abs[β] -> (Subscript[x, 11] + Subscript[x, 22] - Sqrt[-4 Abs[Subscript[T, 12]]^2 + 
    (Subscript[x, 11] + Subscript[x, 22])^2])/(2 Abs[Subscript[T, 12]]), 
    Abs[β] -> (Subscript[x, 11] + Subscript[x, 22] + Sqrt[-4 Abs[Subscript[T, 12]]^2 + 
    (Subscript[x, 11] + Subscript[x, 22])^2])/(2 Abs[Subscript[T, 12]])}
```

and then `β` itself

```
Simplify[Solve[eq /. #, β] & /@ %] // Flatten
(* {β -> (Subscript[T, 12] (Subscript[x, 11] + Subscript[x, 22] - 
    Sqrt[-4 Abs[Subscript[T, 12]]^2 + (Subscript[x, 11] + Subscript[x, 22])^2]))
    /(2 Abs[Subscript[T, 12]]^2), 
    β -> (Subscript[T, 12] (Subscript[x, 11] + Subscript[x, 22] + 
    Sqrt[-4 Abs[Subscript[T, 12]]^2 + (Subscript[x, 11] + Subscript[x, 22])^2]))
    /(2 Abs[Subscript[T, 12]]^2)} *)
```